# java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/sonarqube/gradle/SonarQubePlugin

Tags: java, gradle

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/sonarqube/gradle/SonarQubePlugin : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

  > org/sonarqube/gradle/SonarQubePlugin : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

java -version

java version "1.8.0_102"

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_102-b14)

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.102-b14, mixed mode)

What's wrong?

Comment: You are trying to use code compiled with Java8 with a JVM version lower than Java8.  You will likely need to upgrade your JVM to Java8 to get this to work.

Comment: It isn't duplicate. Trouble with plugin Sonarqube.